# Web Sockets in Spring MVC 3.2 and HTML5

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, websocket

I want to use Web HTML5 sockets with Spring MVC. A few days ago I heard that Spring 3.2 release will come up with Web Sockets support for real time updates.

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/08/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-techniques-for-real-time-updates/

But still not able to find any sample code which provide me the facility of real time update. I am using Tomcat for this purpose now but want to shift to Spring. Please see if you can help me finding a very good example of to use Web HTML5 sockets with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the blog post there's this paragraph:

> Coming back to Spring MVC 3.2, the Servlet 3 async feature can be used for long-running requests and also for HTTP streaming, techniques Filip Hanik referred to as "the server version of client AJAX calls". As for WebSockets, there is no support yet in Spring 3.2 but it will most likely be included in Spring 3.3. You can watch SPR-9356 for progress updates.

So there is no support for WebSockets in Spring MVC 3.2. The [SPR-9356] issue says that the feature is in the  Spring 4.0 backlog. [1](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9356)