# Implementing WebSocket in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websocket

I have a Spring MVC application. UI makes some asynchronous requests to back end. Backend processes the requests and sends the response. Current implementation is done with the help of queues and listeners.
I want to replace it with Web Sockets.
I understand that JDK 7 supports websockets out of the box. 
My application gets deployed on different servers like Tomcat 6.0, WebSphere Application Server etc. Would it make any difference?

> Spring MVC does not support WebSocket so what is the work aorund?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Sockets in Spring MVC 3.2 and HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614456/web-sockets-in-spring-mvc-3-2-and-html5)

Comment: Java EE 7 support Web Socket, not JDK 7.

Answer (score 1):

There's no support for WebSockets in Spring 3.2 There's a log for it in Spring 4 [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9356)

There's also a blog post about how to use it in Spring 4 [here](http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html)

Answer (score 1):

Spring released 4.0 GA which supports Websocket, tomcat 7.0.47+ will be required for the websocket implementation.
http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/12/announcing-spring-framework-4-0-ga-release